# Detach from screen session inside bash script

Tags: gnu-screen

I would like to run a bash scrpit while using a screen session, here is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 5 18 20
do
screen -S output_${i}
./run_my_program
screen -d
```

The problem is that the screen session does not detach using `screen -d` (but detach with the keyboard shortcut ctrl-a d), any suggestion ?
Thanks.

Comment: That also probably doesn't start the `./run_my_program` within the screen, but waits for the first `screen` to return? Do you mean you want to start a detached screen session with some command?

Comment: @ilkkachu actually it start the program but don't close the screen session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to "enter" the screen session to get it to run, just use `-dm` and it will start the session in detached mode:

```
for i in i 5 18 20; do
    screen -dm -S "output_$i" ./run_my_program
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, `"output_${i}"` is the name of my screen session write.

Comment: @liquid-snake right, the `-S` argument names the session

Comment: What to do if I need to add an extra command before running my program, like `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 && ./run_my_program` ?

Comment: @liquid-snake `screen` will inherit values from the parent, so you could always set/update the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` variable prior to launching, or if the script could take that as an argument, you could pass it that way, or you could run a shell to set the variable for you:  `screen ... sh -c "OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./run_my_program"`

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine now, as you suggest I just run `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` befor the `screen -dm -S .....`. Thanks again Eric.